# Mysql update set all null then set column where id in one query

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to first set all  values to null then set value in a single query.

In other words, possible to this in single query:

```
UPDATE table SET column = NULL;
UPDATE table SET column = 'value' WHERE id = 'id';
```

Comment: What does it has to do with php and eloquent? You want a solution in php/eloquent?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte Update tags would be implementing in php/eloquent, but only query would be enough.

Comment: You could use a case statement - but I'm not clear what the second update is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE table 
SET column = CASE WHEN id = 'id' THEN 'value' END;
```

This will update column `column` only in the row(s) with `id = 'id'` to the value `'value'` and all the other rows will be set to `null`.